# svn-externals with own svn-externals: how to recursively checkout?

Tags: svn

So I'm using svn:externals to checkout an external repo. The external repo has its own svn-externals set up.

Now, when updating the working copy of my project, the files from the external repo are being updated, but its externals are not. Is that behavior as designed, can it be extended to also update the external dependencies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recursive checkout are supported since Subversion1.5, as this [thread illustrates](http://old.nabble.com/Recursive-externals-problem-td20924420.html).

The ["Version Control with Subversion" book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externals.html) does mention `svn checkout`, `svn update`, `svn switch`, and `svn export` commands as able to recurse in the externals repos, but:

- If an external is set for a particular revision, no amount of '`update`' will change any file in it, even though the external repo has had new revisions.
- the update must be always initiated from the parent repo, not directly from the sub-repo:

> Be careful, though, that you don't inadvertently modify your external working copy in subtle ways that cause problems.
> For example, while an externals definition might specify that the external working copy should be held at a particular revision number, if you run `svn update` directly on the external working copy, Subversion will oblige, and **now your external working copy is out of sync** with its declaration in the primary working copy.

So maybe one of those two cases applied here.

---

The OP [Carsten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/412944/carsten) reports:

> It is actually working now.
>
> I had set the externals prop on the root node of the external project (lets say project '`lib`').
> In my concrete project (project '`A`'), the external was defined on a sub-folder of '`lib`' (ie. `myLocalFolder > lib/someFolder`).
> That seems to be the reason for subversion not recursing into `lib`'s externals; only looked inside '`someFolder`', didn't find external defs there, so it didn't checkout `someFolder/externalLib`.
> Now, in '`lib`' I changed externals definitions so that they are defined inside the folder that I refer to in '`A`'; works like a charm now!

Comment: Thanks for the thorough info!

Comment: It is actually working now. 

Fyi. I had set the externals prop on the root node of the external project(lets say project 'lib'). In my concrete project(project 'A'), the external was defined on a sub-folder of 'lib'(ie. myLocalFolder > lib/someFolder).
That seems to be the reason for subversion not recursing into lib's externals; only looked inside 'someFolder', didnt find external defs there, so didnt checkout someFolder/externalLib.

Now, in 'lib' I changed externals definitions so that they are defined inside the folder that I refer to in 'A'; works like a charm now!

Comment: @Carsten: excellent :) I have added your conclusion in the answer.